# PDE Example: Where Did $u(x, t) - t^2 = 0$ Come From?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

My lecture notes give the following:

> Consider the PDE $\dfrac{ \partial{u(x, t)} }{ \partial{t}} = 2t$.
>
> Writing this as $\dfrac{ \partial }{ \partial{t}} (u(x, t) - t^2) = 0$,
>
> we see that $u(x, t) - t^2$ must not vary in time and hence solutions of this PDE must be of the form $u(x, t) = t^2 + A(x)$, where $A(x)$ is an arbitrary function.
>
> To make the solution unique, we need more information, in this a boundary condition of the form $u(x, 0) = g(x)$,
>
> so that the unique solution to the PDE with the associate boundary (initial) condition is $u(x, t) = t^2 + g(x)$.

I'm not sure where $\dfrac{ \partial }{ \partial{t}} (u(x, t) - t^2) = 0$ came from?

I tried to derive these calculations as follows:

$\dfrac{ \partial{u(x, t) } }{ \partial{t} } = 2t$

$\therefore \int \dfrac{ \partial{u(x, t) } }{ \partial{t} } \ dt = \int 2t \ dt$

$\rightarrow u(x, t) = t^2 + A(x, t)$ **(ERROR: this should be $A(x)$, as per Botond's comment!!!)**

$\rightarrow u(x, t) - t^2 = A(x, t)$

$\therefore \dfrac{ \partial }{ \partial{t} } (u(x, t) - t^2) = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{t}} A(x, t)$

So I got $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{t}} A(x, t)$, whereas the lecture notes have $0$.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to review this. Am I misunderstanding something? Or is there an error in the lecture slides?

Comment: Why do you have $A(x,t)$? I think it should just be $A(x)$.

Comment: Isn't it clear that the partial derivative w.r.t. of $u(x,t)-t^2$ is $\dfrac{\partial(u(x,t)}{\partial t}-\dfrac{\partial(t^2)}{\partial t}=\dfrac{\partial(u(x,t)}{\partial t}-2t$?

Comment: @Botond Hmm, but $u$ is a function of both $x$ and $t$, so wouldn't the arbitrary function have to be $A(x, t)$?

Comment: @Bernard Oh wow, I completely misread it. My apologies. Just to confirm, shouldn't the arbitrary function be $A(x, t)$ in this situation?

Comment: No. Try to differentiate your equation and see if you get the initial equation.

Comment: @Botond You're right. My apologies, and thank you for the clarification. If that went unchecked it could have been bad later on, haha. :)

Comment: Concerning $A(x,t)$, another way to say it is that it's the integration constant (constant w.r.t. $t$, of course, since the derivative is  w.r.t. $t$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as Bernard wrote in the comments:
$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}t^2 = 2t$. Hence, you get
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x,t)=2t\Leftrightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x,t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}t^2\Leftrightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x,t)-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}t^2=0\Leftrightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(u(x,t)-t^2\right)=0.
$$
At the last step, you use that the derivative is a linear operator.

In your argument, there is a mistake at
$$
\int 2tdt = t^2+A(x,t).
$$
The function $A$ can't depend on $t$. You might think of the additive constant at the integration. But it is a constant wrt the integration variable (in this case $t$). On the other hand, the constant can depend on the remaining variables, like $x$ in your example. So, you should write
$$
\int 2t~dt = t^2+A(x)
$$
such that $A$ just depends on $x$. Naturally, so get $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}A(x)=0$ as you need.

Comment: Yes, I completely misread it. My apologies everyone.